# How to do a select inside an insert using Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am a beginner in postgresql and databases in general.  I have a table with a column product_id.  Some of the values in that column are null.  I need to change those null values to the values from another table.

I want to do something like this:

```
insert into a(product_id) (select product_id from b where product_name='foo') where product_id = null;
```

I realize that this syntax doesn't work but I just need help figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table name is "a" and you have some null product_id, but the othe colums does contain data.

So you need to UPDATE, not to INSERT.
Your Query will be something like this :

```
Update a
set product_id = select product_id from b where b.product_name = 'foo' 
Where product_id is null
```

be sure that your sub query (select ..from b) return a unique value.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
INSERT INTO a (product_id)
select product_id from b where product_name='foo';
```

your where condition is wrong after the) bracket I.e. **where product_id = null**;

Comment: I just realized that I am an idiot and this needs to be an update not an insert...